# Redmine on IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am wondering if anyone has successfully managed to get Redmine installed and running off IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2.)  I have gone through so many walk-throughs explaining how to get RoR running properly for this in Windows 2008 and Windows 2003, however nothing for 2008 R2.  You would think the Windows 2008 steps would still apply to 2008 R2 but this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

In complete honesty, I'm not familiar with Ruby but I'm good at research. lol. If this link I give you helps you, then I'm glad.

If not, I hope someone comes along and figures it out.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickhodge/archive/2009/02/23/windows-7-iis-7-5-and-ruby-on-rails.aspx